# Rxjs: How to bind subject in pipe?

Tags: rxjs

I would like to integrate a subject into a pipe such that later operators can subscribe to earlier observables.

Context: I want to implement a more sophisticated "debounce" where only certain events can block certain other events.
For that, first I want to reimplement "debounce".

This is what I have in mind:

```
const debounced = myEventStream.pipe(
    useSubject(futureEvents => pipe(
        flatFilter(
            myEvent => race(
                interval(10).pipe(map(x => true)),
                futureEvents.pipe(/* filter(...), */ map(x => false))
            )
        )
    )),
);
```

`useSubject` would provide the following stages of the pipe with an observable of future events. Thus, if `flatFilter` would exist, events are not filtered, if the interval triggers first, but filtered, if a newer event comes in.

Is such an `useSubject` reasonable - can it work? Does such an `useSubject` already exists?

Answer (score 0):

It works like a charm:

```
function mergeFilter<T>(
    predicate: (arg: T) => Observable<boolean>
): MonoTypeOperatorFunction<T> {
    return mergeMap(evt =>
        predicate(evt).pipe(
            take(1),
            filter(e => e),
            map(e => evt)
        )
    );
}

function useSubject<T, O>(
    fn: (o: Observable<T>) => OperatorFunction<T, O>
): OperatorFunction<T, O> {
    return function(input: Observable<T>): Observable<O> {
        const subject = new Subject<T>();
        const observer: PartialObserver<T> = subject;
        return input.pipe(
            tap(observer),
            fn(subject)
        );
    };
}

function debounceTime<T>(time: number) {
    return useSubject<T, T>(futureEvents =>
        mergeFilter(myEvent =>
            race(
                // allow event after 10ms
                interval(10, s).pipe(map(x => true)),
                // discard event when new event arrived
                futureEvents.pipe(map(x => false))
            )
        )
    );
}
```

This is still a lot shorter than the original `rxjs` debounce implementation, but its performance might be worse.